# How to use Pageable in a non-repository spring boot project that uses data from json file?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data

I know how to use Spring Boot's pagination in a project extending a Repository (`CrudRepository`, `JpaRepository`) by simple adding `Pageable` to the repository like this:

```
class myRepository extends CrudRepository<T, Long> {
List<T> findAll(Long id, Pageable pageable);
}
```

But now I'm making a project wherein I'm getting data from a json file by using jackson's `ObjectMapper` with this:

```
class getJson(){
List<JsonNode> jsonList;
File file = new File("jsonfile");
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper().readTree(file);
//process of adding file content to jsonlist
return jsonlist;
}
```

The `RestController` I made can access the data. This easy setup makes everything work thanks to Spring magic. I'm using `GET method`. So yeah it's working how I want it to be.

But now I want to add Pagination. I've tried this:

```
Page<JsonNode> pageableData() throws IOException {
Page<JsonNode> results = consumer.getJson();
return results;
}
```

But it says they're incompatible types requiring `Page` instance but receiving a `List` instance. I understand why there's an error, but I just don't know what to do. I don't know how to make add pagination to my controller using Spring Boot's "magic."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `PageImpl` object, it takes as input parameters a List, a pageable and a number of total elements. Assuming you got a `pageable` from your controller:

```
...
    List<JsonNode> results = consumer.getJson();
    return new PageImpl(results, pageable, results.size());
...
```

Comment: Got it. I saw the PageImpl pop up, but I wasn't sure it was the right way because when I saw that it was an abstract class I thought that it was just being used by another class. My bad. I'll try this answer as soon as possible. Sorry but I can't open my intelliJ for now, I'm doing something that's taking up quite some RAM. Thanks!

Comment: i've tried that. but the pagination service isn't working.

Comment: gonna mark this as correct anyway. it solved my current problem.